# Remove product delete button from admin

Tags: admin, adminhtml, products-management

Is there a way to remove the delete button from the manage products backend? I understand that this would make it impossible to remove products. Preferably, it would not require a change to the core.

Comment: Hei MagentoNoob, Welcome to Magento Stackeexchange. if you dont want to delete a product, then ignore that button. Why would you bother to delete it ? Could you please explain the reason by editing your question ?

Comment: @programmer_rkt - Ever worked with a team of 'content editors' who seem to not have that ability, to ignore delete buttons.

Comment: @ProxiBlue : I am sorry. I didn't get your point actually !!!!

Comment: @programmer_rkt : Staff manages your products, and product content. Periodically products seem to disappear. Your developer finds that the products were deleted.  You tell the staff to ignore the delete button (as suggested) A week later you find that products have again been deleted (accidents happen)

Comment: @ProxiBlue : now I got your point. What if we just disable that delete button for those `content-editors`. May be its possible if we write a small module for that by using magento's great `ACL` feature. So that only admin users can use delete button. I think that is the proper way of doing this stuff, instead of removing the delete button entirely. What would you think ?

Comment: @programmer_rkt - I agree - consider the fact that you can also delete via mass-action from the grid, making hiding a button pointless as well. MagentoNoob - understanding your requirements/why would help. I also don't understand why people are voting for this to be closed. There is a clear question being asked. We may not agree with what is being asked, but that for me does not justify closing the question.

Comment: @ProxiBlue: When I first I look into this problem, I just feel this question will definitely closed by "unclear question" and in fact I also voted for it. Now I too feel that this question should not be closed.. So after giving a proper edit by giving WHY it is necessary, I think we can re-open this question.

Comment: @ProxiBlue actually this question is lagged by that WHY. if we add that to the question then it become a perfect valid question which deserve to be upvoted...

Answer (score 5):

If you are worried of people accidentally clicking the delete button you can take the simple approach @Prashanta suggested. Hiding it via css. It should work.
If you want to completely remove the delete button and the delete action you need to rewrite the product edit block and the product admin controller.  You also need to remove the mass action delete from the grid.
For this you will need a custom extension. Let's call it `StackExchange_Catalog`.
You will need the following files.

`app/etc/modules/StackExchange_Catalog.xml` - the declaration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <StackExchange_Catalog>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Catalog />
                <Mage_Adminhtml />
            </depends>
        </StackExchange_Catalog>
    </modules>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/StackExchange/Catalog/etc/config.xml` - the configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <StackExchange_Catalog>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </StackExchange_Catalog>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <catalog_product_edit>StackExchange_Catalog_Block_Adminhtml_Product_Edit</catalog_product_edit><!-- remove the delete button -->
                    <catalog_product_grid>StackExchange_Catalog_Block_Adminhtml_Product_Grid</catalog_product_grid><!-- remove the mass action delete -->
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules><!-- disallow delete actions -->
                        <StackExchange_Catalog before="Mage_Adminhtml">StackExchange_Catalog_Adminhtml</StackExchange_Catalog>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/StackExchange/Catalog/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit.php` - your version of the product edit block

```
<?php
class StackExchange_Catalog_Block_Adminhtml_Product_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit
{
    /**
     * no delete button for you
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDeleteButtonHtml()
    {
        return '';
    }
}
```

`/app/code/local/StackExchange/Catalog/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Grid.php` - your grid version that removes the mass action delete.

```
<?php
class StackExchange_Catalog_Block_Adminhtml_Product_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid
{
    protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        parent::_prepareMassaction();
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->removeItem('delete');
        return $this;
    }
}
```

`app/code/local/StackExchange/Catalog/controllers/Adminhtml/Catalog/ProductController.php` - your new product controller that disables the delete action just in case someone guesses the delete URL. This should never happen but let's be paranoid.

```
<?php
require_once 'Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php';
class StackExchange_Catalog_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController
{
    /**
     * just redirect to index on the delete action
     */
    public function deleteAction()
    {
        $this->_getSession()->addWarning($this->__('Product deletion is prohibited'));
        $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
    }

    /**
     * don't allow mass delete either
     */
    public function massDeleteAction()
    {
        $this->_getSession()->addWarning($this->__('Product deletion is prohibited'));
        $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! The only full and complete answer on this entire "internet" thing.

Answer (score 1):

Just use plain and simple css. Add this code to your css file.

```
.adminhtml-catalog-product-edit button.delete { display: none; }
```

Comment: It is not a Magento way. You may say this as a tiny hack. Marius answer is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Here below simple way to remove delete button from admin panel.For that override `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` in your extension as below

```
<global>
    <models>
      <catalog>
        <rewrite>
          <product>MY_PACKAGE_Model_Product</product>
        </rewrite>
      </catalog>
    </models>
  </global>
```

Now create new `Product.php` file in `Model` with below code.

```
class MY_PACKAGE_Model_Product extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
{
    protected $_isDuplicable = false; // Remove Duplicate Button
    protected $_isDeleteable = false; // Remove Delete Button
}
```